# How to nest ItemsControl with multiple ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `ConfigList` object with a name and a `Dictionary` and I need to nest `ItemsControls` with different `ItemsSource`.

I tried to do it this way :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TestStep" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConfigList }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ictrl.Nom}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Param}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" : " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ItemsControl>
```

When I start my application, I've got this error :

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException : '' Adding a value to the
> collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an
> exception. ' line number '25' and line position '14'. '

> Internal Exception
> InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation when ItemsSource is in
> use. Access and edit items with ItemsControl.ItemsSource.

Any idea what ​​the problem is?

Comment: The exceptions results from using both `ItemsSource` and `Items` which is forbidden. The way you add the nested ItemsControl in XAML implicitly adds it as element of its Items collection. Which is not allowed since you already bind to ItemsSource.
You probably want to add the nested ItemsControl to the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set an `ItemsSource` on the `ItemsControl`. The data template is used to create the controls that display the data. The created items are then put into the `Items` collection of the `ItemsControl`. If you add an element to the `ItemsControl` directly in XAML this will put them into the `Items` collection, too. Doing both is not allowed. You either specify an `ItemsSource` or add to `Items` directly. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> Note that you use either the Items or the `ItemsSource` property to specify the collection that should be used to generate the content of your `ItemsControl`. When the `ItemsSource` property is set, **the `Items` collection is made read-only and fixed-size**.

However, in your case this is not the real issue, because your markup is wrong for what you want to achieve. If you you really intended to nest `ItemsControl`s, you would simply change the data template for the outer `ItemsControl` to contain another `ItemsControl` that binds to a collection property within the outer data item. Since there is already a `TextBox`, you have to use a panel (e.g. `StackPanel`) to host multiple controls in the template.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TestStep" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConfigList }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ictrl.Nom}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Param}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                                <TextBlock Text=" : " />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you want to have a hierarchical view of your data, using a [`TreeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/treeview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) might be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I understood my mistake. It works now.